# How to log on a web app with SAP user's credentials?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, sap-gui

I am trying to make a login on a web app that authenticates those credentials against a user's SAP login credentials. How can I do that? What is this called? Is this an HTTP request or something else?

Comment: it depends on which type of authentication is used in SAP. Also you didn't put which tech stack your web app is based on

Comment: What are you talking about? Which software from SAP company? Which Web application? Your question is **very unclear**, it's like asking "how do I log in Microsoft Web app, is it with HTTP?" with no other information.